# Windows Mobile & Windows Phone development on one box?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I've been developing for Windows Mobile/Pocket PC for a number of years without any issues.  I recently started getting "Unable to start debugging" error messages after I installed Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Phone 7.1 SDK.  The Visual Studio 2008 Remote tools would work, and Visual Studio could deploy the files, but "Start with Debugging" would not work while "Start without Debugging" would work.

I uninstalled the Windows Phone 7 SDK and am able to debug Windows Mobile applications again.  Is there any way to allow the Windows Mobile 6.x and Windows Phone 7 SDKs to coexist on one computer?

Comment: While it's not an answer (hence me not posting it as one) I've got two PCs - this one included - that have both Studio 08 and Studio 10 installed and that I've been able to do both Phone and WinMo development with, so it's certainly possible to have both.

Comment: +1 to Chris. I think this is a case of Microsoft's VS team not tying up all of their loose ends - and they don't appear to care to go back to fix it.

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing WP7 tools it's now working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trevor, this issue has been reported as a bug with a known workaround by Jeffrey Walton on Microsoft Connect. The fix is summarized as follows:

- Rename the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SmartDevices\Debugger\target\wce400\armv4i` to `armv4i_temp`
- Copy the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\Debugger\target\wce400\armv4i` inside the Visual Studio 2010 path.

Reference: [VS 2010 Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools breaks existing VS 2008 Windows Mobile Developer Tools](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/644844/installing-vs-2010-and-windows-phone-7-developer-tools-breaks-exisitng-vs-2008-and-windows-mobile-developer-tools)

Answer (score 2):

With these Errors Double Check and make sure Service Pack one is installed for 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 can not build (much less debug) a Windows Mobile application. It can develop for Windows Phone 7 (apparently - I certainly do not develop for it).

To develop (build/debug) for Windows Mobile, drop back to Visual Studio 2008. That's the last version of Visual Studio that offered support for Windows Mobile.

Unfortunate.

Comment: I'm saying Visual Studio 2008 won't debug a Smart Device application if Windows Phone 7.1 SDK is installed on the PC.  Removing the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK makes the Visual Studio 2008 debugger work again.  Visual Studio 2008 + 2010 can still compile projects while the 7.1 SDK is installed, but 2008 will never debug a Smart Device application as long as the 7.1 SDK is installed.

Comment: Why does that not surprise me? I tend to think that members of Microsoft's Smart Device Team do not fully understand everything they are developing. Perhaps there is something in the Service Pack, as Keeano Martin suggested. I doubt it, though. I'm certainly not installing the Phone 7.1 SDK if this is the case! Does Phone 7.0 have these same issues? Is there a Phone 7.1 SDK Service Pack?

Answer (score 1):

Right edm2.exe and other remote debugger Arm4i files versions must be deployed to device. Rename temporarily all folders containing edm3.exe and try VS2008 debug. If works, search edm*.exe in registry and repair related keys to VS2008only state.